# Assigning Day or Night to a time

Tags: python, pandas

trying to assign Day or Night to a time based on the hour. Data set looks like this:

```
'Date'
2021-06-09 14:00:00
2021-06-09 13:00:00
2021-06-09 15:00:00
2021-06-09 16:00:00
2021-06-09 17:00:00
2021-06-09 18:00:00
2021-06-09 19:00:00
ect...
```

I would like to create a new column that is "Day" or "Night" based on the time. I wanted it to be "Day" from 0700-1800. Tried several things but nothing is working. Very new to Python here.

Comment: Use `column.dt.hour` then implement your logic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a really lazily set up trivial data frame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'date': pd.Timestamp('2020-01-01 15:00')}])
```

Just query for the hour, then ask whether it is between 7 and 18 (6p), address inclusivity if desired, then map `True` to `day` and `False` to `night`.

```
df['dayness'] = df['date'].dt.hour.between(7, 18, inclusive=True) \
    .replace({True: 'day', False: 'night'})
```

Output is then:

```
df['dayness']
0    day
Name: date, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If the column is a datetime column

```
df['Is_Day'] = df['Date'].df.hour.between(7, 18, inclusive=True)
df['Is_Day'] = df['Is_Day'].replace({True: "Day", False: "Night"}
```

To make it a datetime column, try:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```